# I can expand my div, but how do I shrink it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a series of divs that, when clicked, expand a div immediately beneath each one of them. When another div is clicked, any previously expanded div is closed and the one below the clicked div is expanded. This is working really nicely. My problem is that clicking on the already open div should shrink the div beneath it, but it doesn't. 
My code is based on this example...
https://wpbeaches.com/create-expandcollapse-faq-accordion-collapse-click/
This example works perfectly - clicking any div closes any other div, including its own if it's already open. 
My code works well, but clicking a div doesn't close the div below it if it's already open.

CSS:

```
        /* Style the element that is used to open and close the accordion class */
        div.accordion {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            transition: 0.4s;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            opacity: 0.70;
            filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        }

        /* Add a background color to the accordion if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
        div.accordion.active, div.accordion:hover {
            background: rgb(255,255,255);
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(232,231,222,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
            opacity: 1;
            filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        }

        /* Style the element that is used for the panel class */

        div.panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            background-color: white;
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
            opacity: 0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        div.panel.show {
            opacity: 1;
            max-height: 500px; /* Whatever you like, as long as its more than the height of the content (on all screen sizes) */
        }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');

        for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function() {
                var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
                setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
                setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');

                if (setClasses) {
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                }
            }
        }

        function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
            for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                els[i].classList[fnName](className);
            }
        }

        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

My html is just like the code in the wpbeaches.com example above.

Answer (score 0):

Add removing logic in your else case or remove the if condition since you are using toggle function. In your case, the toggle is working similar to the add method. Just check with the code

```
            if (setClasses) {
                this.classList.add("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
            } else {
                this.classList.remove("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
            }
```

Comment: Thanks very much Prashanth. I tried adding your else case but it made no difference (the expanded div still didn't close). I also tried removing the if statement but then no divs would open or close at all.

Comment: I have tried to replicate your issue on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/prashanth-kuppanan/pen/gyKrzr). I click the question and the answer got opened. I clicked the opened question and the answer which is opened gets closed. Is this you are asking not happened to you?

Comment: Thank you so much Prashanth for taking the time to do that. I've finally worked out why it wasn't working with my version. In my accordion divs I have a table. I'd inadvertently assigned a class of 'accordion' to each <tr>, as well as to the containing div. Once I removed the class from the <tr> it works perfectly. I really have no idea why I did that in the first place, other than stupidity! Thanks again, you've been a great help!

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is clicking on answer link doesn't close the question but if we click on already open question, it will close the respective answer. It's because you applied the onClick function only on accordian "p" element and not on panel "div" element.

**You can apply 1 common class to both accordian and panel element and apply onCLick function on that class.**

```
acc[i].onclick = function() {
```

Comment: Yes, when I click an already open question again, I want it to close, just like the example. Mine only closes the answer when I click on a different question - not the parent question. The difference between the example code and my own, is that I removed the css that displays the + and - button on each question. 
You can probably tell that javascript definitely isn't one of my stronger points!

Comment: Sorry tbaveja - I've just re-read your message. I don't want to be able to click on the answer. I only want to be able to click on the question - once to open it and once to close it again. Clicking on any question closes any other open questions (correctly) but it doesn't close itself if it is already open.

Comment: It's working for me and I guess working on codepen as well, as mentioned by Prashanth as well. Can you please tell me on which browser and OS you're running above code.

Comment: Thank you so much tbaveja for taking the time to look at this. You and Prashanth have both been a big help. Please see my response to Prashanth above.